# Adding multiple directed edges in networkx

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, edges

I know this should be very basic but I have no clue how to do this using networkx. What I am trying to do is to create a MultiDiGraph with 20 nodes. There would be 2 edges connecting each nodes to each other, one away from the node and the other going towards the node. I am unable to create those edges. Any help would be greatly appreciated. It should look something like the picture I have attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a graph, and then convert it to a directed graph. In this way you get edges in both directions:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)])
g = g.to_directed()
```

```
>>> g.edges
OutEdgeView([(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1)])
```

If you want to generate a complete directed graph with n nodes:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.complete_graph(4).to_directed()
```

```
>>> g.edges
OutEdgeView([(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!